# Property [X] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a basic laravel 9 crud app.

There I have two tables in my db. companies and employees.

I'm trying to display single-user details on my employees.show blade

All my data is displayed correctly but when I try to print user's company, I'm kept getting the following error.

> Property [company] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Following is my employee model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'company_id'
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
```

and the following is the show function in my controller

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
    {
        $data = Employee::with('company')->where('id', '=', $employee->id);
        return view('employees.show', compact('employee','data'));
    }
```

and this is my show.blade

```
<div class="row mb-4">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-label-form"><b>Company</b></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {{ $data->company->name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

How can I display the company properly...

I have company_id as a foreign key in my employees' table...

I have following when I `dd $data`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries) from the `Employee` query in your `show()` function. You want to add `->get()` to return a `collection` or `Employee` records:

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
{
    $data = Employee::with('company')->where('id', '=', $employee->id)->get();
    return view('employees.show', compact('employee','data'));
}
```

Comment: I made the change, but now it's giving me an error saying, Property [company] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @ArcticFox Do all your `Employee` records have an associated `Company`?

Comment: yes, all the emps are assigned to a company

Comment: Do a `dd($data);` in your `show()` function and check what is being returned.

Comment: I've updated the question with the output...
#attributes: array:8 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "first_name" => "AC"
        "last_name" => "Hampton"
        "email" => "isfdfdf@gmail.com"
        "phone" => "775439571"
        "company_id" => 4
        "created_at" => "2022-10-17 00:34:54"
        "updated_at" => "2022-10-17 08:06:44"
      ]

Comment: @ArcticFox What is inside the `relations` array, that is the important part.

Comment: I've added another ss

Comment: @ArcticFox Can you add how you are using `$data` in your `employees.show.blade.php` file? Please include as much code as is relevant. I suspect you're using `$data` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in Query for get data. In **employees.show** you only show one data then and in controller you got collection of data as array. So your single data element can't access because it is array and for execution you need to add foreach loop for that.

Here you need to change query method from `get()` to `first()` and it will resolve your issue.

Your show function code looks like this

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
{
    $data = Employee::with('company')->where('id', '=', $employee->id)->first();
    return view('employees.show', compact('employee','data'));
}
```

Your employees.show blade looks like this

```
<div class="row mb-4">
     <label class="col-sm-2 col-label-form"><b>Company</b></label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ $data->company->name }}
           </div>
</div>
```